# Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 - all worked on former

Tags: wireless, upgrade, bluetooth, touchscreen, external-monitor

I have been using 20.04 for a few months and had issues but was still able to work albeit cursor flickering and random crashes. It became untenable today and thought to upgrade to 22.04. Did so and nothing works No WiFI No link to HDMI connected External Monitor Bluetooth does not work. I cannot do a thing without connectivity. I'm a beginner. I reinstalled 20.04 alongside 22.04 so i had connectivity but now cannot see my documents.
On neither version does my touch screen or pen work on my MS Surface Pro 6. I am desperate. What do i do? Gently with the technicality of any advise or help. Thanks

Comment: surface devices often need a special linux kernel in order for all the parts of them to work properly. See https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup

Comment: Thanks You very much BUT....there is (--dearmor) in there which is stopping progress. now entirely clueless

Comment: as mentioned i am useless but trying to learn. Did not grow up with this. I'm likewise not a youngster but I refuse to support MS.

Comment: You already had issues with ubuntu 20.04 which is a Long-Term-Support version that has received patches for years. Maybe you are able to find details about your hardware. Computer brand, etcetera. You can find out by opening a new terminal window (ctrl-alt-t) and enter the following command: sudo lshw | head -n 10. You will then see the exact brand and type of your computer/laptop. People might then be able to help you with known issues.